# How to change Default Description of a NEW CL on Perforce Helix P4V

Tags: perforce, p4v, changelist, perforce-client-spec

I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find the exact thing I was looking for. I am using P4V (not the command line). When I right-click and select the option "New Pending Changelist", a dialog box opens up that allows me to select which files to add and allows me to edit the description. By default, the description text is: "<enter description here>". I want to change this default text to custom text. I am not asking how to change the description of an existing CL or how to do this on the server side etc. This is just for my own client, and when I am using P4V. I want the default text to be something different than "<enter description here>"

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in option to have a custom default description other than one set server-side, but I do something similar.

I'm running Windows and have a "changedesc.bat" file with the contents of: `p4 --field Description="No ticket req'd." change -o | p4 change -i`

I can run this standalone, or as part of a custom tool (way easier). If you save this as an .xml file and import it into Tools (Tools-->Manage Tools-->Custom Tools) and choose "Import Custom Tools..." and import it (after editing to match your own, naturally) it will include this as option when right-clicking on any pending changelist, including the default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--perforce-xml-version=1.0-->
<CustomToolDefList varName="customtooldeflist">
<CustomToolDef>
<Definition>
<Name>MyDescription</Name>
<Command>C:\P4\custom_tools\changedesc\changedesc.bat</Command>
<Arguments>%C</Arguments>
<Shortcut></Shortcut>
</Definition>
<AddToContext>true</AddToContext>
</CustomToolDef>
</CustomToolDefList>
```

Comment: Heck, you could even add a shortcut to save yourself a click.